# Weeding out lengthy Durations

Tags: sql-server, datediff

I only want to keep durations less than 10 minutes long. my current code is as follows:

```
Duration = DateDiff(ss, TimeBegin, TimeEnd)
```

TimeBegin and TimeEnd are in TIME format. Obviously Duration right now comes back as:

```
00:00:07
```

That's where I'm running into trouble. Can I use a statement that looks like this:

```
<= 00:10:00 or <= '00:10:00'
```

Essentially I want:

```
Duration = (Datediff(ss, TimeBegin, TimeEnd) *ONLY IF LESS THAN 10 MINUTESg)
```

I already state earlier in the query that if no result is returned to create a NULL, so when a duration is Greater than 10 minutes, I just want it to be ignored as if it didn't exist.

Comment: Hmm.  Is this T-SQL?  If so, you need `@` in front of your variable names, `Set` before assigning values, and `DATEDIFF` returns integers, not time values.  But the syntax is also wrong for the VB DateDiff function (the first parameter is a string and so would need double quotes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateDiff(ss, TimeBegin, TimeEnd)` gives you the difference in seconds.  Just use a `Case` statement to return the value only if that's under 600 (`...ELSE Null` is implied):

```
set @Duration = CASE
 WHEN DateDiff(ss, @TimeBegin, @TimeEnd) < 600
 THEN DateDiff(ss, @TimeBegin, @TimeEnd)
END;
```

Comment: This worked. It not T-SQL so I left out the @ but it worked out great thank you.

Comment: Agreed. But with some exceptions described below.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with @aucuparia. But (this is for topic starter) be careful with using datediffs is seconds instead of minutes. Their behavior isn't the same, like months/years datediffs. I mean server rounds your operands:

```
select datediff(mi,'2014-05-15 19:00:00','2014-05-15 19:10:59')
```

is not the same like

```
select datediff(ss,'2014-05-15 19:00:00','2014-05-15 19:10:59')
```

Just execute them both and see the difference. The first one still is 10-minutes difference, but the second will be cut off by 600-seconds 'where' clause.

Comment: OK I see what you're saying. Thanks for the heads up.